# Run Worksheet_SelectionChange event while Inputbox active

Tags: excel, vba, input, event-handling

I have an inputbox set up to ask a user to select a range. When selecting the range I would like the selection to automatically be resized to certain dimensions, so the user can see the new selection before clicking OK (before setting myRange).

I have set up a Worksheet_SelectionChange event to handle resizing the selection. The problem is that the selectionChange event doesn't work while the inputbox is active.

This is the code snippet that appears in my module:

```
InputboxActive=True   
    Set myRange = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Range Selection", Type:=8)
InputboxActive=False
```

This code appears in my worksheetChange sub:

```
if InputboxActive=True then Target.resize(5,10).select
```

The selectionChange event doesn't run while the inputbox is active. How do I fix this?

Any assistance would be appreciated, thanks

Comment: You could use a refedit control on a userform if the inputbox isn't working for you.

Comment: Creating a userform is an option, but I'm more wondering whether this is an excel feature that worksheet events are disabled when specifically the built-in inputbox is active, or if there is something else that is the matter. And if it's not the default behaviour then how do I identify the issue

Answer (score 0):

Add `myRange.Select` after you set myRange, which as

```vb
Set myRange = Application.InputBox("Select a range", "Range Selection", Type:=8)
myRange.Select
```

That should trigger the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event

Comment: I would like the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event to trigger before the user clicks on OK (before myRange is set, while the inputbox is still active), so that they can be sure it is the correct range they are selecting, and select elsewhere if it isn't what they wanted to select.